# Overriding JS Alert() message with a Modal UI

Tags: javascript

I realized the SweetAlert2 is not working for me and Im trying to integrate jQuery to override Alert() by putting a basic dialog window divs in HTML and JS calling IDs like this and it seems it doesnt work -

HTML

```
<html>
<script src="action.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="board-outer" class="center">
    <table id="board">
        <tr class="row">
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('A')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="A" alt="Top-Left"></a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('B')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="B" alt="Top-Center"></a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('C')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="C" alt="Top-Right"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('D')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="D" alt="Middle-Left"></a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('E')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="E" alt="Middle-Center"></a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('F')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="F" alt="Middle-Right"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('G')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="G" alt="Bottom-Left"></a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('H')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="H" alt="Bottom-Center"></a></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('I')"><img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="I" alt="Bottom-Right"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br>
   <div class="center button">
    <button onClick="playAgain();"><img src="restart.gif" width="111" height="98" border="0"></button>
</div>

<div id="dialog1" title="Basic dialog"> <-----------------
    <p>You won!</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog2" title="Basic dialog"> <-----------------
    <p>Computer wins!</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog3" title="Basic dialog"> <-----------------
    <p>Tied!</p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.center {margin: auto;}
body {background-color: #000000;}
.button {margin: auto;width: 102px;height: 95px;}
.center button {background-color: #000000;border: none;}
#board-outer {background-color: none;overflow: hidden;}
#board {width: 750px;height: 750px;background-color: none;border-spacing: 0; margin: auto;}
td {height: 246px;width: 246px;text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse;  border: 7px solid #000000;background-color: #333333;}
a,.title {color: #b24926;}
#content a:hover {color: #333;}
#banner-secondary p.intro {padding: 0;float: left;width: 50%;}
#banner-secondary .download-box {border: 1px solid #aaa;background: #333;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #333 0%, #444 100%);background: linear-gradient(to right, #333 0%, #444 100%);float: right;width: 40%;text-align: center;font-size: 20px;padding: 10px;border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);}
#banner-secondary .download-box h2 {color: #71d1ff;font-size: 26px;}
#banner-secondary .download-box .button {float: none;display: block;margin-top: 15px;}
#banner-secondary .download-box p {margin: 15px 0 5px;}
#banner-secondary .download-option {width: 45%;float: left;font-size: 16px;}
#banner-secondary .download-legacy {float: right;}
#banner-secondary .download-option span {display: block;font-size: 14px;color: #71d1ff;}
#content .dev-links {float: right;width: 30%;margin: -15px -25px .5em 1em;padding: 1em;border: 1px solid #666;border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px -2px #666;}
#content .dev-links ul {margin: 0;}
#content .dev-links li {padding: 0;margin: .25em 0 .25em 1em;background-image: none;}
.demo-list {float: right;width: 25%;}
.demo-list h2 {font-weight: normal;margin-bottom: 0;}
#content .demo-list ul {width: 100%;border-top: 1px solid #ccc;margin: 0;}
#content .demo-list li {border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;margin: 0;padding: 0;background: #eee;}
#content .demo-list .active {background: #fff;}
#content .demo-list a {text-decoration: none;display: block;font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px;color: #3f3f3f;text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;padding: 2% 4%;}
.demo-frame {width: 70%;height: 350px;}
.view-source a {cursor: pointer;}
.view-source > div {overflow: hidden;display: none;}
</style>
```

Javascript

```
// VARIABLES
<!-- 
var x = "x.gif";
var o = "o.gif";
var blank = "blank-sq.gif";
var pause = 0;
var all = 0;
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;
var e = 0;
var f = 0;
var g = 0;
var h = 0;
var i = 0;
var temp="";
var ok = 0;
var cf = 0;
var choice=9;
var aRandomNumber = 0;
var comp = 0; 
var t = 0;
var wn = 0;
var ls = 0;
var ts = 0;

function logicOne() {
if ((a==1)&&(b==1)&&(c==1)) all=1;
if ((a==1)&&(d==1)&&(g==1)) all=1;
if ((a==1)&&(e==1)&&(i==1)) all=1;
if ((b==1)&&(e==1)&&(h==1)) all=1;
if ((d==1)&&(e==1)&&(f==1)) all=1;
if ((g==1)&&(h==1)&&(i==1)) all=1;
if ((c==1)&&(f==1)&&(i==1)) all=1;
if ((g==1)&&(e==1)&&(c==1)) all=1;
if ((a==2)&&(b==2)&&(c==2)) all=2;
if ((a==2)&&(d==2)&&(g==2)) all=2;
if ((a==2)&&(e==2)&&(i==2)) all=2;
if ((b==2)&&(e==2)&&(h==2)) all=2;
if ((d==2)&&(e==2)&&(f==2)) all=2;
if ((g==2)&&(h==2)&&(i==2)) all=2;
if ((c==2)&&(f==2)&&(i==2)) all=2;
if ((g==2)&&(e==2)&&(c==2)) all=2;
if ((a != 0)&&(b != 0)&&(c != 0)&&(d != 0)&&(e != 0)&&(f != 0)&&(g != 0)&&(h != 0)&&(i != 0)&&(all == 0)) all = 3;
} 

function logicTwo() {
if ((a==2)&&(b==2)&&(c== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((a==2)&&(b== 0)&&(c==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="B";
if ((a== 0)&&(b==2)&&(c==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((a==2)&&(d==2)&&(g== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
if ((a==2)&&(d== 0)&&(g==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="D";
if ((a== 0)&&(d==2)&&(g==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((a==2)&&(e==2)&&(i== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((a==2)&&(e== 0)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((a== 0)&&(e==2)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((b==2)&&(e==2)&&(h== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="H";
if ((b==2)&&(e== 0)&&(h==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((b== 0)&&(e==2)&&(h==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="B";
if ((d==2)&&(e==2)&&(f== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="F";
if ((d==2)&&(e== 0)&&(f==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((d== 0)&&(e==2)&&(f==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="D";
if ((g==2)&&(h==2)&&(i== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((g==2)&&(h== 0)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="H";
if ((g== 0)&&(h==2)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
if ((c==2)&&(f==2)&&(i== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((c==2)&&(f== 0)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="F";
if ((c== 0)&&(f==2)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((g==2)&&(e==2)&&(c== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((g==2)&&(e== 0)&&(c==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((g== 0)&&(e==2)&&(c==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
}

function logicThree() {
if ((a==1)&&(b==1)&&(c==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((a==1)&&(b==0)&&(c==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="B";
if ((a==0)&&(b==1)&&(c==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((a==1)&&(d==1)&&(g==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
if ((a==1)&&(d==0)&&(g==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="D";
if ((a==0)&&(d==1)&&(g==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((a==1)&&(e==1)&&(i==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((a==1)&&(e==0)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((a==0)&&(e==1)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((b==1)&&(e==1)&&(h==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="H";
if ((b==1)&&(e==0)&&(h==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((b==0)&&(e==1)&&(h==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="B";
if ((d==1)&&(e==1)&&(f==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="F";
if ((d==1)&&(e==0)&&(f==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((d==0)&&(e==1)&&(f==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="D";
if ((g==1)&&(h==1)&&(i==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((g==1)&&(h==0)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="H";
if ((g==0)&&(h==1)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
if ((c==1)&&(f==1)&&(i==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((c==1)&&(f==0)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="F";
if ((c==0)&&(f==1)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((g==1)&&(e==1)&&(c==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((g==1)&&(e==0)&&(c==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((g==0)&&(e==1)&&(c==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
}

function clearOut() {
document.game.you.value="0";
document.game.computer.value="0";
document.game.ties.value="0";
}

function checkSpace() {
if ((temp=="A")&&(a==0)) {
    ok=1;
        if (cf==0) a=1;
        if (cf==1) a=2;
            }
if ((temp=="B")&&(b==0)) {
    ok=1;
        if (cf==0) b=1;
        if (cf==1) b=2;
        }
if ((temp=="C")&&(c==0)) {
    ok=1;
        if (cf==0) c=1;
        if (cf==1) c=2;
        }
if ((temp=="D")&&(d==0)) {
    ok=1;
        if (cf==0) d=1;
        if (cf==1) d=2;
        }
if ((temp=="E")&&(e==0)) {
    ok=1;
        if (cf==0) e=1;
        if (cf==1) e=2;
        }
if ((temp=="F")&&(f==0)) {
    ok=1
        if (cf==0) f=1;
        if (cf==1) f=2;
        }
if ((temp=="G")&&(g==0)) {
    ok=1
        if (cf==0) g=1;
        if (cf==1) g=2;
        }
if ((temp=="H")&&(h==0)) {
    ok=1;
        if (cf==0) h=1;
        if (cf==1) h=2;
        }
if ((temp=="I")&&(i==0)) {
    ok=1;
        if (cf==0) i=1; 
        if (cf==1) i=2; 
        }                   
}

function yourChoice(chName) {
pause = 0;
if (all!=0) ended();
if (all==0) {
    cf = 0;
    ok = 0;
    temp=chName;
    checkSpace();
if (ok==1) {
    document.images[chName].src = x;
    }
if (ok==0)taken();
    process();
if ((all==0)&&(pause==0)) myChoice();
     }
}

function myChoice() {
temp="";
ok = 0;
cf=1;
logicTwo();
logicThree();
checkSpace();
    while(ok==0) {
        aRandomNumber=Math.random()
        comp=Math.round((choice-1)*aRandomNumber)+1;
if (comp==1) temp="A";
if (comp==2) temp="B";
if (comp==3) temp="C";
if (comp==4) temp="D";
if (comp==5) temp="E";
if (comp==6) temp="F";
if (comp==7) temp="G";
if (comp==8) temp="H";
if (comp==9) temp="I";
    checkSpace();
    }
document.images[temp].src= o;
    process();
    }


function process() {
logicOne();
if (all==1)
    { 
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog(); <-----------------
        }
if (all==2)
    { 
        $( "#dialog2" ).dialog(); <-----------------
        }
if (all==3)
    { 
        $( "#dialog3" ).dialog(); <-----------------
        }
    }

function playAgain() {
if (all==0) {
    reset();
}
if (all>0) reset();
}

function reset() {
all = 0;
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
e = 0;
f = 0;
g = 0;
h = 0;
i = 0;
temp="";
ok = 0;
cf = 0;
choice=9;
aRandomNumber = 0;
comp = 0; 
    document.images.A.src= blank;
    document.images.B.src= blank;
    document.images.C.src= blank;
    document.images.D.src= blank;
    document.images.E.src= blank;
    document.images.F.src= blank;
    document.images.G.src= blank;
    document.images.H.src= blank;
    document.images.I.src= blank;
if (t==0) { t=2; myChoice(); }
    t--;
}

//   -->
```

Comment: There are libraries that do this for you such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com)

Comment: I would recommend https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The function `taken` does not exist, in which case the code would error out before it ever hits `process`. (I added one in the example below.)
- `all` is always 0, so `$(...).dialog()` never fires in `process`. (Something's up with your logic.)

I've made an example `dialog0` for you to show `all` is always 0. See the code snippet below.

```js
var x = "x.gif";
var o = "o.gif";
var blank = "blank-sq.gif";
var pause = 0;
var all = 0;
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;
var e = 0;
var f = 0;
var g = 0;
var h = 0;
var i = 0;
var temp = "";
var ok = 0;
var cf = 0;
var choice = 9;
var aRandomNumber = 0;
var comp = 0;
var t = 0;
var wn = 0;
var ls = 0;
var ts = 0;

function logicOne() {
  if ((a == 1) && (b == 1) && (c == 1)) all = 1;
  if ((a == 1) && (d == 1) && (g == 1)) all = 1;
  if ((a == 1) && (e == 1) && (i == 1)) all = 1;
  if ((b == 1) && (e == 1) && (h == 1)) all = 1;
  if ((d == 1) && (e == 1) && (f == 1)) all = 1;
  if ((g == 1) && (h == 1) && (i == 1)) all = 1;
  if ((c == 1) && (f == 1) && (i == 1)) all = 1;
  if ((g == 1) && (e == 1) && (c == 1)) all = 1;
  if ((a == 2) && (b == 2) && (c == 2)) all = 2;
  if ((a == 2) && (d == 2) && (g == 2)) all = 2;
  if ((a == 2) && (e == 2) && (i == 2)) all = 2;
  if ((b == 2) && (e == 2) && (h == 2)) all = 2;
  if ((d == 2) && (e == 2) && (f == 2)) all = 2;
  if ((g == 2) && (h == 2) && (i == 2)) all = 2;
  if ((c == 2) && (f == 2) && (i == 2)) all = 2;
  if ((g == 2) && (e == 2) && (c == 2)) all = 2;
  if ((a != 0) && (b != 0) && (c != 0) && (d != 0) && (e != 0) && (f != 0) && (g != 0) && (h != 0) && (i != 0) && (all == 0)) all = 3;
}

function logicTwo() {
  if ((a == 2) && (b == 2) && (c == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "C";
  if ((a == 2) && (b == 0) && (c == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "B";
  if ((a == 0) && (b == 2) && (c == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "A";
  if ((a == 2) && (d == 2) && (g == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "G";
  if ((a == 2) && (d == 0) && (g == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "D";
  if ((a == 0) && (d == 2) && (g == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "A";
  if ((a == 2) && (e == 2) && (i == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "I";
  if ((a == 2) && (e == 0) && (i == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "E";
  if ((a == 0) && (e == 2) && (i == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "A";
  if ((b == 2) && (e == 2) && (h == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "H";
  if ((b == 2) && (e == 0) && (h == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "E";
  if ((b == 0) && (e == 2) && (h == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "B";
  if ((d == 2) && (e == 2) && (f == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "F";
  if ((d == 2) && (e == 0) && (f == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "E";
  if ((d == 0) && (e == 2) && (f == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "D";
  if ((g == 2) && (h == 2) && (i == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "I";
  if ((g == 2) && (h == 0) && (i == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "H";
  if ((g == 0) && (h == 2) && (i == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "G";
  if ((c == 2) && (f == 2) && (i == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "I";
  if ((c == 2) && (f == 0) && (i == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "F";
  if ((c == 0) && (f == 2) && (i == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "C";
  if ((g == 2) && (e == 2) && (c == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "C";
  if ((g == 2) && (e == 0) && (c == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "E";
  if ((g == 0) && (e == 2) && (c == 2) && (temp == "")) temp = "G";
}

function logicThree() {
  if ((a == 1) && (b == 1) && (c == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "C";
  if ((a == 1) && (b == 0) && (c == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "B";
  if ((a == 0) && (b == 1) && (c == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "A";
  if ((a == 1) && (d == 1) && (g == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "G";
  if ((a == 1) && (d == 0) && (g == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "D";
  if ((a == 0) && (d == 1) && (g == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "A";
  if ((a == 1) && (e == 1) && (i == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "I";
  if ((a == 1) && (e == 0) && (i == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "E";
  if ((a == 0) && (e == 1) && (i == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "A";
  if ((b == 1) && (e == 1) && (h == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "H";
  if ((b == 1) && (e == 0) && (h == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "E";
  if ((b == 0) && (e == 1) && (h == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "B";
  if ((d == 1) && (e == 1) && (f == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "F";
  if ((d == 1) && (e == 0) && (f == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "E";
  if ((d == 0) && (e == 1) && (f == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "D";
  if ((g == 1) && (h == 1) && (i == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "I";
  if ((g == 1) && (h == 0) && (i == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "H";
  if ((g == 0) && (h == 1) && (i == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "G";
  if ((c == 1) && (f == 1) && (i == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "I";
  if ((c == 1) && (f == 0) && (i == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "F";
  if ((c == 0) && (f == 1) && (i == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "C";
  if ((g == 1) && (e == 1) && (c == 0) && (temp == "")) temp = "C";
  if ((g == 1) && (e == 0) && (c == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "E";
  if ((g == 0) && (e == 1) && (c == 1) && (temp == "")) temp = "G";
}

function clearOut() {
  document.game.you.value = "0";
  document.game.computer.value = "0";
  document.game.ties.value = "0";
}

function checkSpace() {
  if ((temp == "A") && (a == 0)) {
    ok = 1;
    if (cf == 0) a = 1;
    if (cf == 1) a = 2;
  }
  if ((temp == "B") && (b == 0)) {
    ok = 1;
    if (cf == 0) b = 1;
    if (cf == 1) b = 2;
  }
  if ((temp == "C") && (c == 0)) {
    ok = 1;
    if (cf == 0) c = 1;
    if (cf == 1) c = 2;
  }
  if ((temp == "D") && (d == 0)) {
    ok = 1;
    if (cf == 0) d = 1;
    if (cf == 1) d = 2;
  }
  if ((temp == "E") && (e == 0)) {
    ok = 1;
    if (cf == 0) e = 1;
    if (cf == 1) e = 2;
  }
  if ((temp == "F") && (f == 0)) {
    ok = 1
    if (cf == 0) f = 1;
    if (cf == 1) f = 2;
  }
  if ((temp == "G") && (g == 0)) {
    ok = 1
    if (cf == 0) g = 1;
    if (cf == 1) g = 2;
  }
  if ((temp == "H") && (h == 0)) {
    ok = 1;
    if (cf == 0) h = 1;
    if (cf == 1) h = 2;
  }
  if ((temp == "I") && (i == 0)) {
    ok = 1;
    if (cf == 0) i = 1;
    if (cf == 1) i = 2;
  }
}

function yourChoice(chName) {
  pause = 0;
  if (all != 0) ended();
  if (all == 0) {
    cf = 0;
    ok = 0;
    temp = chName;
    checkSpace();
    if (ok == 1) {
      document.images[chName].src = x;
    }
    if (ok == 0) taken();  // <--- this function does not exist
    process();
    if ((all == 0) && (pause == 0)) myChoice();
  }
}

function taken() { } // <--- inserted this here just for testing

function myChoice() {
  temp = "";
  ok = 0;
  cf = 1;
  logicTwo();
  logicThree();
  checkSpace();
  while (ok == 0) {
    aRandomNumber = Math.random()
    comp = Math.round((choice - 1) * aRandomNumber) + 1;
    if (comp == 1) temp = "A";
    if (comp == 2) temp = "B";
    if (comp == 3) temp = "C";
    if (comp == 4) temp = "D";
    if (comp == 5) temp = "E";
    if (comp == 6) temp = "F";
    if (comp == 7) temp = "G";
    if (comp == 8) temp = "H";
    if (comp == 9) temp = "I";
    checkSpace();
  }
  document.images[temp].src = o;
  process();
}


function process() {
  logicOne();
  if (all === 0) { // <----- all is always 0.
    $("#dialog0").dialog();
  }
  else if (all == 1) {           
    $("#dialog1").dialog(); //<-----------------
  }
  else if (all == 2) {
    $("#dialog2").dialog(); //<-----------------
  }
  else if (all == 3) {
    $("#dialog3").dialog(); //<-----------------
  }
}

function playAgain() {
  if (all == 0) {
    reset();
  }
  if (all > 0) reset();
}

function reset() {
  all = 0;
  a = 0;
  b = 0;
  c = 0;
  d = 0;
  e = 0;
  f = 0;
  g = 0;
  h = 0;
  i = 0;
  temp = "";
  ok = 0;
  cf = 0;
  choice = 9;
  aRandomNumber = 0;
  comp = 0;
  document.images.A.src = blank;
  document.images.B.src = blank;
  document.images.C.src = blank;
  document.images.D.src = blank;
  document.images.E.src = blank;
  document.images.F.src = blank;
  document.images.G.src = blank;
  document.images.H.src = blank;
  document.images.I.src = blank;
  if (t == 0) {
    t = 2;
    myChoice();
  }
  t--;
}
```

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
}
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.button {
  margin: auto;
  width: 102px;
  height: 95px;
}
.center button {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: none;
}
#board-outer {
  background-color: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#board {
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
td {
  height: 246px;
  width: 246px;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 7px solid #000000;
  background-color: #333333;
}
a,
.title {
  color: #b24926;
}
#content a:hover {
  color: #333;
}
#banner-secondary p.intro {
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#banner-secondary .download-box {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #333;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #333 0%, #444 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #333 0%, #444 100%);
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#banner-secondary .download-box h2 {
  color: #71d1ff;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#banner-secondary .download-box .button {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#banner-secondary .download-box p {
  margin: 15px 0 5px;
}
#banner-secondary .download-option {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#banner-secondary .download-legacy {
  float: right;
}
#banner-secondary .download-option span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #71d1ff;
}
#content .dev-links {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  margin: -15px -25px .5em 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px -2px #666;
}
#content .dev-links ul {
  margin: 0;
}
#content .dev-links li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: .25em 0 .25em 1em;
  background-image: none;
}
.demo-list {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
}
.demo-list h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#content .demo-list ul {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}
#content .demo-list li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
#content .demo-list .active {
  background: #fff;
}
#content .demo-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  padding: 2% 4%;
}
.demo-frame {
  width: 70%;
  height: 350px;
}
.view-source a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.view-source > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="board-outer" class="center">
  <table id="board">
    <tr class="row">
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('A')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="A" alt="Top-Left">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('B')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="B" alt="Top-Center">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('C')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="C" alt="Top-Right">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('D')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="D" alt="Middle-Left">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('E')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="E" alt="Middle-Center">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('F')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="F" alt="Middle-Right">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('G')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="G" alt="Bottom-Left">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('H')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="H" alt="Bottom-Center">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:yourChoice('I')">
          <img src="blank-sq.gif" border="0" height="246" width="246" name="I" alt="Bottom-Right">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<div class="center button">
  <button onClick="playAgain();">
    <img src="restart.gif" width="111" height="98" border="0">
  </button>
</div>

<div id="dialog0" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>All is 0.</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog1" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>You won!</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog2" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Computer wins!</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog3" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Tied!</p>
</div>
```